# How to automatically fill in a blank column

Tags: r, loops, cumulative-sum

I am trying to get the list of sums of two columns from my original data set, from left to right
[image]

I have made a loop:

```
for (i in 1:ncol(df)) { 
m = i
n = i + 1
if (i %% 2 != 0) {
df_cum$V1 <- sum(df[,m] + df[,n])
}
}
```

But, the way to add value to the new list is wrong:

```
df_cum$V1 <- sum(df[,m] + df[,n])
```

would be really appreciated if anyone knows how to do that in R

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `split.default()`, i.e.

```
sapply(split.default(df, gsub('\\d+', '', names(df))), sum)
 A  B 
17 12
```

Comment: Hi Sotos, this method is so quick! thanks a lot : ) but another file of mine has column names "GC001home","GC001company", "GC002home","GC002company". I was wondering how can i change the '\\d+' to get the sum of "GC001" and "GC002"? Many thanks !!

Comment: You can do `gsub('home|company', '', names(df))`. The rest remains the same

Answer (score 0):

We can do this in `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%   
    pivot_longer(everything(), names_to = c(".value", "grp"), 
           names_sep ="(?<=[A-Z])(?=[0-9])") %>%
    select(-grp) %>%    
    summarise(across(everything(), sum, na.rm = TRUE), .groups = 'drop')
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 1 x 3
      A     B     C
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1    17    12    13
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
aggregate(values ~ ., transform(stack(df1), 
            ind = sub("\\d+", "", ind)), FUN = sum)
  ind values
1   A     17
2   B     12
3   C     13
```

---

Or another option with `rowsum` from `base R`

```
with(stack(df1), rowsum(values, group = trimws(ind, whitespace = "\\d+")))
  [,1]
A   17
B   12
C   13
```

---

Or another option is with `colSums` and `rowsum`

```
{tmp <- colSums(df1); rowsum(tmp, group = substr(names(tmp), 1, 1))}
  [,1]
A   17
B   12
C   13
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(A1 = c(0, 3, 2), A2 = c(2, 6, 4), B1 = c(3, 0, 
1), B2 = c(2, 3, 3), C1 = c(7, 3, 2), C2 = c(1, 0, 0)), 
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Answer (score 0):

A base R option using `tapply` -

```
tapply(unlist(df), 
       rep(1:ncol(df), each = nrow(df) * 2, length.out = nrow(df) * ncol(df)), 
       sum)

# 1  2  3 
#17 12 13
```

The logic here is to create group of every 2 columns and `sum` them.

**data**

It is easier to help if you provide data in a [reproducible format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)

```
df <- data.frame(A1 = c(0, 3, 2), A2 = c(2, 6, 4), 
                 B1 = c(3, 0, 1), B2 = c(2, 3, 3), 
                 C1 = c(7, 3, 2), C2 = c(1, 0, 0))
```